# Can't run Apache 2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 - Forbidden

Tags: 14.04, apache2, lamp

I recently installed a fresh version of Gnome Ubuntu 14.04
I then used tasksel to install lamp server

Then I did like I do always

```
usermod -a -G www-data $USER
mkdir /srv/www/html
cp /var/www/html/index.html /srv/www/html/index.html
chown -R $USER:www-data /srv/www

gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Changed

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

To

```
DocumentRoot /srv/www/html
```

Then

```
service apache2 reload
```

The result

**Forbidden**

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Read the release notes http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html and couldn't get to the issues..

I attempted different setups to match my old environments and messed around with apache2 and PHP, but started over again and attempted the simplest thing, I couldn't even get that to work

Please help or point me in the right direction

This is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ku9i08t9cag9ivz/AADgE9CUclLQYw09DNIvF2xea?dl=0) to the current conf files (apache2.conf, 000-default.conf)

Comment: Did you check if is present <[Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory) /path> directive? If yes, you should change it too. Also use service apache2 restart.

Comment: There's no Directory directive and I did try restart

Comment: It is strange, did you check `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and  `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`?

Comment: Yes I checked them to my best knowledge, and note that I only edited 000-default.conf nothing more

Comment: Sounds like a permissions problem. Try forcing the ownership of /var/www to www-data:www-data. Also, make sure the directory is 0664. Personally, I like to add group sticky to my web root like this: `chmod g+s /folder` so that no matter which user put the file in, it's owned by the folder's group (www-data) and is accessible to Apache.

Comment: I did I tried every scenario concerning ownership and permissions including www-data:www-data with 775. I think there's something new with the apache2.4.7 that's not properly stated in the release notes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to change `DocumentRoot` from `/var/www/html` to `/srv/www/html`, open `apache.conf` and change:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

with:

```
<Directory /srv/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Save `apache2.conf` and restart apache:

```
sudo service apache restart
```

Comment: Thanx I missed that

Comment: I have a strange thing happening. When I have `AllowOverride None` i.e. bypassing `.htaccess` reading under `/var/www` node I can see the homepage and any other page is 404! When I make it to `All` the homepage is also giving 404. I have opened a secured tunnel using `ngrok http -subdomain=local.mysite 80`. Both `ngrok` and `local.mysite.com` are wither opening homepage only or giving 404 based on`AloowOverride` value. I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. How can I  resolve this issue?

Comment: @NiladriSarkar I suggest to open a new question where you could give a full description of your problem and so, you will have a better chance to get help.

Comment: @Lety Thanks for your suggestion. Meanwhile I realized where the issue was! It was `.htaccess` permission. I changed the permission to 644 and everything came back to normal! Sorry for putting my question in wrong place.